# If certificate authority generates key pair for us, do they maintain/have access to our private key?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

[image]

If they do keep our private key and by chance if anyone within the CA organization listen to our conversation. Isn't it a confidentiality breakage?

Answer (score 6):

This is a bad model. The proper way to request a certificate is to send a [CSR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) (certificate signing request) to the certificate authority

The CSR contains your **public key only** (it is signed using your private key to prove that you own the private key, and to ensure integrity of the request contents).

You **should not** use a mechanism where the CA generates the private key for you, it is not needed and only adds more ways for your private key to leak.

**Final note**: as usual, context matters a lot: if the scenario involves certificate issuance within an organization (eg: internal CA for corporate infrastructure) it might be acceptable, especially if the organization has a good process in place for key management. If possible show the source of the slide, it might make more sense in context.

Comment: For an example of how this can go wrong: Trustico was storing private keys clients had generated online, and were amazingly lax about securing them, leading to [23,000 certificates having to be revoked with minimal notice](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/03/23000-https-certificates-axed-after-ceo-e-mails-private-keys/). (Trustico is apparently still in business. I don't know why; I'd never trust them for *anything* after that.)

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't it a confidentiality breakage?

It depends how you define confidentiality. If you mean that nobody except the private key owner is authorized to know the private key, than yes it is a confidentiality breakage. But in some organizations there can be a policy that allows also some other persons (e.g. system administrators) to know user passwords or to have a copy of their private key. Means such persons are *authorized* to know this information. Thus this would not be a breakage. Breakage is the case when persons are *unauthorized*.

The picture in your question contains a *misleading* text "Example (Good)". In some cases like described above it can be fine. But in others, e.g. if user needs a certificate for private goals, such scheme is not good, but disastrous.